# Cannot access keychain in ad hoc mode

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

My app was just rejected on itunes connect due to a bug.

When i check it, i realized that crash was caused by keychain access.

In debug mode, it works good, it can set and get values to keychain but when it comes to Ad Hoc mode, it cannot get or set any data to keychain. It returns `nil` when it tries to get a value.

I use this to set value

```
TegKeychain.set("userID", value: userID)
```

And using this to get value

```
var userid = TegKeychain.get("userID")
```

And this framework https://github.com/exchangegroup/keychain-swift

Comment: Show the code you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the code used for retrieving data fixed this issue

```
 var result: AnyObject?
    let status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&result) {
        SecItemCopyMatching(query, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
    }

    return status == noErr ? result as? NSData : nil
```